# Apache Flink and Stateful Function: NoSuchMethodError When Submitting Flink Job

Tags: function, apache-flink, stateful

I'm trying to use an embedded stateful function from apache flink code but am getting the following error. The dependencies I am using are 1.17.0 of Apache Flink and 3.2.0 of statefun-flink-datastream (Stateful Functions). I've looked at the code in an IDE and the method giving the exception below appears to be present.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator.getSideOutput(org.apache.flink.util.OutputTag)'
    at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.translation.Sinks.lambda$sideOutputStreams$0(Sinks.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.common.Maps.transformValues(Maps.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.translation.Sinks.sideOutputStreams(Sinks.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.translation.StatefulFunctionTranslator.translate(StatefulFunctionTranslator.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.translation.EmbeddedTranslator.translate(EmbeddedTranslator.java:61) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.datastream.StatefulFunctionDataStreamBuilder.build(StatefulFunctionDataStreamBuilder.java:157) ~[?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

Statefun 3.2.0 only support Flink 1.14.3. There is no Statefun version which supports a later Flink version at this moment